# file does not upload after being chosen

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I want to upload a file in CodeIgniter in such a way that when I choose the file it should gets uploaded without clicking `upload` button explicitly. I have written following piece of code for doing this. However, with this code only the file chooser pops-up but the file does not upload after choosing it, i.e. the `form` is not being submitted. So please tell what can be the issue in my code?

**Code:**

```
<?php
    echo form_open_multipart('transferdata/uploadfile');
?>
<form action = "" method = "" id="uploadForm">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" style="display: none;" onchange="document.getElementById('uploadForm').submit(); this.value=null; return false;" />
    <a class="toolbar" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('userfile').click();">
        <span title="Upload" class="icon-32-upload"></span>
        Upload
    </a>
</form> 
<?php
    echo form_close();
?>
```

Comment: `onchange` event isn't fired perhaps?

Comment: Why are you using `<form action = "" method = "" id="uploadForm">` when the form is already generated using `echo form_open_multipart('transferdata/uploadfile');` ?

Comment: you need `method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"` to upload a file of course ...

Comment: yea its pretty obvious that the form tags are duplicated

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    echo form_open_multipart('transferdata/uploadfile');
?>
```

This will already create the `<form>` tag with `enctype`.

Please remove the inside `<form action = "" method = "" id="uploadForm">` tag and try again.